# build_attrs() got an unexpected keyword argument 'id'

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am trying to get date input with month and year drop-down menus. 
I am using a widget from django snippet.

About the widget: 
A Widget that splits date input into two  boxes for month and year,
with 'day' defaulting to the first of the month.

Here's the code of the widget

```
import datetime
import re
from six import string_types
from django.forms.widgets import Widget, Select
from django.utils.dates import MONTHS
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

__all__ = ('MonthYearWidget',)

RE_DATE = re.compile(r'(\d{4})-(\d\d?)-(\d\d?)$')


class MonthYearWidget(Widget):
    """
    A Widget that splits date input into two <select> boxes for month and year,
    with 'day' defaulting to the first of the month.

    Based on SelectDateWidget, in

    django/trunk/django/forms/extras/widgets.py


    """
    none_value = (0, '---')
    month_field = '%s_month'
    year_field = '%s_year'

    def __init__(self, attrs=None, years=None, required=True):
        # years is an optional list/tuple of years to use in the "year" select box.
        self.attrs = attrs or {}
        self.required = required
        if years:
            self.years = years
        else:
            this_year = datetime.date.today().year
            self.years = range(this_year, this_year+10)

    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):
        try:
            year_val, month_val = value.year, value.month
        except AttributeError:
            year_val = month_val = None
            if isinstance(value, string_types):
                match = RE_DATE.match(value)
                if match:
                    year_val, month_val, day_val = [int(v) for v in match.groups()]

        output = []

        if 'id' in self.attrs:
            id_ = self.attrs['id']
        else:
            id_ = 'id_%s' % name

        month_choices = list(MONTHS.items())
        if not (self.required and value):
            month_choices.append(self.none_value)
        month_choices.sort()
        local_attrs = self.build_attrs(id=self.month_field % id_)
        s = Select(choices=month_choices)
        select_html = s.render(self.month_field % name, month_val, local_attrs)
        output.append(select_html)

        year_choices = [(i, i) for i in self.years]
        if not (self.required and value):
            year_choices.insert(0, self.none_value)
        local_attrs['id'] = self.year_field % id_
        s = Select(choices=year_choices)
        select_html = s.render(self.year_field % name, year_val, local_attrs)
        output.append(select_html)

        return mark_safe(u'\n'.join(output))

    def id_for_label(self, id_):
        return '%s_month' % id_
    id_for_label = classmethod(id_for_label)

    def value_from_datadict(self, data, files, name):
        y = data.get(self.year_field % name)
        m = data.get(self.month_field % name)
        if y == m == "0":
            return None
        if y and m:
            return '%s-%s-%s' % (y, m, 1)
        return data.get(name, None)
```

I am getting this errror in my browser

```
TypeError: build_attrs() got an unexpected keyword argument 'id'
```

My python version is 3.7.0 and Django version is 2.0.7

How to get rid of this error?

Comment: where is build_attrs method ??? does it take an ID value ?

Comment: You probably want `build_attrs(extra_attrs={'id': self.month_field % id_})`

Comment: @OhadtheLad even I had the same doubt and searched for the method, but couldn't find it

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem so should I replace build_attrs with extra_attrs everywhere in the code?

Comment: @OhadtheLad: it is a function of `Widget`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/_modules/django/forms/widgets/

Comment: @ShashankJerri: where else do you call `build_attrs`?

Comment: Okay, got it @WillemVanOnsem thanks :)

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem u r correct, nice !

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem now I'm gettint a new error that base_attrs() is missing 1 required positional argument: 'base_attrs'

Comment: @ShashankJerri: well then you should probably write it as `attrs={...}` instead.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem attrs={...} was still giving me an error, so instead I tried build_attrs({ 'id': self.month_field % 12 }) and it worked :)

Comment: Sorry I mean `base_attrs`....

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the id value as a dictionary value:

```
local_attrs = self.build_attrs(attrs, {'id':'self.month_field % id_'})
```

In Django 1.11, Widget.build_attrs() signature was changed so it only has two arguments:

[Django 1.11 fix #28095](https://github.com/django/django/commit/e86f4786a7f39b0ed833c0699addf0c27811d864)

See similar issue addressed in stackoverflow question here by user Ruan Steenkamp:
[Update to 1.11: TypeError build_attrs() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44348951/11880369)